# How to merge unknown number of object into one using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm working on a react-native project, and receive data from api just simple like this

```
[
  { 
   "value":[1,2,3.....1250]  //each have max 1250 item, can be have multi of them
  },
  { 
   "value":[1,2,3.....1230]
  }
]
```

Problem is, i don't know how many item like this, maybe 3,4 object have 1250 item, i don't know, so my question is,how to merge 2, or any bigger than single object, object value will look like this if we only have 2 object:

```
[
  {
  "value":[1,2,3...1250,1,2,3..1230]. //will have every value of two object
  }
]
```

How can i do this in lodash??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lodash . You can do this simply with JS Reduce method.

If u really want use lodash, then

`_ is importing lodash as _`

```
_.reduce(arr, (currentArray, currentValueObject) => ([{
      value: [...currentArray[0].value, ...currentValueObject.value] //concatenate current object value to the object valules till now
    }]), [{
      value: [] //the final value array inside object 
    }])
```

```js
var arr = [{
    "value": [1, 2, 3, 1250] //each have max 1250 item, can be have multi of them
  },
  {
    "value": [1, 2, 3, 1230]
  }
]

var result = arr.reduce((currentArray, currentValueObject) => ([{
  value: [...currentArray[0].value, ...currentValueObject.value] //concatenate current object value to the object valules till now
}]), [{
  value: [] //the final value array inside object 
}])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You have some error in lodash code, it can't run @Himashiru

Comment: Have u imported lodash?? I have just given you an example...

Here is the doc https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#reduce